# Unable to append multiple childs

Tags: javascript, html

I'm writing a code where in I need to create a child div and append multiple child nodes dynamically using JS.

Here is my code.

```js
function addDivs() {
  var jsonInput = {
    'a': '1',
    'b': '2'
  }
  var colDiv = document.getElementById("col-md-12");
  var row = document.createElement("div");
  row.className = "row";
  colDiv.appendChild(row);
  Object.keys(jsonInput).forEach(function(k) {
    var string = k;
    var range = jsonInput[k];
    var col4Div = document.createElement("div");
    col4Div.className = "col-md-4 icon-plus";
    var alcohol = document.createElement("span");
    alcohol.className = string;
    var strong = document.createElement("strong");
    strong.innerHTML = string;
    var dropDownArrow = document.createElement("span");
    dropDownArrow.className = "down-arrow";
    row.appendChild(col4Div);
    col4Div.appendChild(alcohol);
    alcohol.appendChild(strong);
    alcohol.appendChild(dropDownArrow);
    alcohol.innerHTML = "<br/>";
    alcohol.innerHTML = range;
  });
}
```

```html
<div id="col-md-12"></div>

<input type="button" onclick="addDivs()" />
```

Here I'm expecting the output as

```
<div class="col-md-12">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 icon-plus">
           <span class="a">
           <strong>a</strong>
           <span class="down-arrow"></span>
           <br /> 1</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 icon-plus">
           <span class="b">
           <strong>b</strong>
           <span class="down-arrow"></span>
           <br /> 2</span>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

but I get the output as

```
 <div id="col-md-12">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 icon-plus">
           <span class="a">1</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 icon-plus">
           <span class="b">2</span>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

please let me know on how can I get this output.

Thanks

Comment: Do a '+=' to keep on concatenating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are keep ovveriding the innerHTML. That is the reason you are not seeing the already appended children.

You have to append it actually

```
    ..
    alcohol.appendChild(dropDownArrow);
    alcohol.innerHTML = "<br/>";
    alcohol.innerHTML = range;
```

That should be,

```
 ..
 alcohol.appendChild(dropDownArrow);
 alcohol.innerHTML = alcohol.innerHTML +"<br/>";
 alcohol.innerHTML = alcohol.innerHTML + range;
```

That way, you can retain the existing html with newly adding html.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

Why this work?

```
alcohol.innerHTML += "<br/>";
alcohol.innerHTML += range;
```

The var `alcohol` is getting overridden but in my code, the variable is getting concatenated. So, the desired output is outputted.

```js
function addDivs() {
  var jsonInput = {
    'a': '1',
    'b': '2'
  }
  var colDiv = document.getElementById("col-md-12");
  var row = document.createElement("div");
  row.className = "row";
  colDiv.appendChild(row);
  Object.keys(jsonInput).forEach(function(k) {
    var string = k;
    var range = jsonInput[k];
    var col4Div = document.createElement("div");
    col4Div.className = "col-md-4 icon-plus";
    var alcohol = document.createElement("span");
    alcohol.className = string;
    var strong = document.createElement("strong");
    strong.innerHTML = string;
    var dropDownArrow = document.createElement("span");
    dropDownArrow.className = "down-arrow";
    row.appendChild(col4Div);
    col4Div.appendChild(alcohol);
    alcohol.appendChild(strong);
    alcohol.appendChild(dropDownArrow);
    alcohol.innerHTML += "<br/>";
    alcohol.innerHTML += range;
  });
}
```

```html
<div id="col-md-12"></div>

<input type="button" onclick="addDivs()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this

```
alcohol.append = "<br/>";
alcohol.innerHTML = alcohol.innerHTML + range;
```

```js
function addDivs() {
  var jsonInput = {
    'a': '1',
    'b': '2'
  }
  var colDiv = document.getElementById("col-md-12");
  var row = document.createElement("div");
  row.className = "row";
  colDiv.appendChild(row);
  Object.keys(jsonInput).forEach(function(k) {
    var string = k;
    var range = jsonInput[k];
    var col4Div = document.createElement("div");
    col4Div.className = "col-md-4 icon-plus";
    var alcohol = document.createElement("span");
    alcohol.className = string;
    var strong = document.createElement("strong");
    strong.innerHTML = string;
    var dropDownArrow = document.createElement("span");
    dropDownArrow.className = "down-arrow";
    row.appendChild(col4Div);
    col4Div.appendChild(alcohol);
    alcohol.appendChild(strong);
    alcohol.appendChild(dropDownArrow);
    alcohol.append = "<br/>";
    alcohol.innerHTML = alcohol.innerHTML + range;
  });
}
```

```html
<div id="col-md-12">

</div>

<input type="button" onclick="addDivs()" />
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `prepend`:

```
$('Selector ').prepend($('<div> new div </div>'));
```

[Jquery link](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)

Comment: Why add jQuery if it's possible without?

Comment: because it is efficient and easy .

Comment: I gave a alternate solution  only .If this solution not works then down vote

Comment: @AmiteshKumar because some ppl don't like jQuery because it is a third party library. And why would the company like Google use jQuery because they have highly skilled developers?

Comment: @AmiteshKumar I am not the downvoter but I know your approach is very much correct. But not correct for the OP because he tagged only plain js and his code only consists plain js